# Button moves by click

Tags: html, css, button

I made a button and when I click on that ;
it moves,and its not fixed!
the style that I wrote for that is :
(signup is the name of class for button)

```
.signup:active {
position:fixed;}
```

Comment: Please show some HTML and perhaps the rest of the CSS that might move it

Comment: why are you using position fixed

Comment: What you CSS is saying: when mouse is down on button, change `position` of button to `fixed`. I guess thats why it moves...

Comment: @StephanWagner  "mouse is down " is "signup.active"
 and in that the position is fixed!!
but why ot moves?!!

Comment: Well your CSS says `.signup:active` not `signup.active`. `:active` is a pseudo class that triggers when the element is active (mouse is down on element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `position: fixed` doesn't mean it is a "fixed" position, it means the position of the button won't change when you scroll. I suggest you read more about CSS style position:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

**What you are doing here with CSS (See my comment above):**
When mouse is down on button, change position of button to fixed. I guess thats why it moves...

And may be you could provide some more information of what you actually want to achieve so we can help you a bit better :)

Comment: You're right, it just was the first result! I'll see if I find a better one. EDIT: done!

Comment: @StephanWagner thank you alot!! :)
i change the position to absulute, and it works correctly...